# While loops within while loops for a beginning programmer in C++

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I'm in an introduction to C++ programming class.  I am suppose to create a program that loops the whole program if a character y is inputted at the end of the program.
I cannot seem to get the loop to loop even when I input the value for y
I have defined the variables as follows:

```
char value, y;
float percent;
value=y;
y=value;
while (value==y)
```

It checks the condition the condition and runs the program the first time, however it does not loop.
The ending statement looks as follows:

```
"cin<< value;"
```

The brackets check out, too.
Is there a rule I'm missing about having multiple while loops within while loops (I have two other loops that work fine inside the bigger loop), or is it because I cannot have the "while (input==y)" as a condition?

Thank you very much

Comment: Ok, `value`, `y`, and `percent` are all uninitialized and using them before you set a value is undefinded behavior. Then you show `"cin << value;"`, which is a *string*, not a line of code. Please show a minimal, complete example code that reproduces the problem you are having.

Comment: Thank you very much Mikhail!  I was completely forgetting the single quotes.  I added them in and now everything works smoothly!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do something like

```
int main() {
    char value = 'a', y;
    do {
        // do something
        cout << "hello" << endl;
        cin >> y;
    } while (y == value);

    return 0;
}
```

It runs the loop once, checks input character at the end and repeats if y equals to the specified value.

Comment: Guess it should be `char value = 'y'` but the principle is correct. I was about to write similar answer when your answer came. So I'll just +1 you instead. BTW: The variable `value` isn't needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't cin works that way? : 
`cin>>value;`
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/
And your condition is good, but if it loop once, its because the value doesn't change (maybe because the cin didn't work because of the syntax?)